# Rails + Nginx + Unicorn increase post data size ( 414 Request-URI Too Large)

Tags: nginx, unicorn, request

I get 414 (Request-URI Too Large)  exception on my POST Request while sending bulk date to my server. Is it possible to increase the limit of POST data?

I have done following change in nginx configuration

```
large_client_header_buffers 8 2024k;
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure this error happens on Nginx level not backend.

Comment: I don't see any log in server.  No calls were made to server

Answer (score 1):

It seems `unicorn` has built-in global default for request length. If some of part exceeds these limits, then `unicorn` will return HTTP 414.

https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn/blob/v5.0.1/ext/unicorn_http/global_variables.h#L63-L68